# How can I adapt this react native code to be able to see the video in full screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, video

What I want to do is play a video of my app made in react native and be able to see it in full screen, when I load the component everything goes well except that when I put the video in full screen the custom controls that I added are removed and the default ones are added . This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Dimensions,
    Text,
} from "react-native";
import { ResizeMode } from "expo-av";
import GeneralStyles from "../../styles/GeneralStyles";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import VideoPlayer from "expo-video-player";

const MyComponent = () => {
    const lastVideo = useRef(null);

    const [fullScreenMode, setFullScreenMode] = useState(ResizeMode.COVER);

    const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");

    return (
        <LinearGradient colors={["#FFFFFF", "#FFEFE3", "#FFE1E1", "#FFFFFF"]}>
            <ScrollView style={GeneralStyles.mainContainer}>
                <View style={[styles.videoContainer]}>
                    <View style={{ padding: 10, borderWidth: 1, backgroundColor: 'black', borderRadius: 10 }}>
                        <VideoPlayer
                            videoProps={{
                                shouldPlay: false,
                                resizeMode: fullScreenMode,
                                source: {
                                    uri: "https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
                                },
                                ref: lastVideo,
                            }}
                            style={{
                                height: width * 1.5,
                                width: width * 0.9,
                                videoBackgroundColor: "transparent",
                                controlsBackgroundColor: "black",
                            }}
                            header={
                                <Text style={{ color: "#FFF", padding: 10 }}>
                                    The title
                                </Text>
                            }
                            autoHidePlayer={{ autoHide: true, duration: 1000 }}
                            activityIndicator={{ size: "large", color: "#FFF" }}
                            slider={{
                                thumbTintColor: "#FFF",
                                margin: 10,
                                minimumTrackTintColor: "#E50000",
                                maximumTrackTintColor: "#FFF",
                            }}
                            fullscreen={{
                                visible: true,
                                enterFullscreen: async () => {
                                    try {
                                        setFullScreenMode(ResizeMode.CONTAIN);
                                        await lastVideo.current.presentFullscreenPlayer();
                                    } catch (error) {
                                        console.log(error);
                                    }
                                },
                                exitFullscreen: async () => {
                                    try {
                                        setFullScreenMode(ResizeMode.COVER);
                                        await lastVideo.current.dismissFullscreenPlayer();
                                    } catch (error) {
                                        console.log(error);
                                    }
                                },
                                controls: {
                                    hide: true,
                                },
                            }}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.dateContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.date}>17/06/2023</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearGradient>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    videoContainer: {
        alignSelf: "center",
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    date: {
        fontSize: 15,
        textAlign: "center",
        fontWeight: 300,
        color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
        padding: 5,
        paddingLeft: 10,
    },
    dateContainer: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        width: "auto",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
});
```

Now, in [the documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video/#presentfullscreenplayer) I read that when using `presentFullscreenPlayer()` (just like I do) the default controls are used even if `useNativeControls` is set to `false`. So how can I make "my controls" show up instead of the normal ones? Do I need to use another library? Or what do I have to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using the expo-video-player package to display and control the video in your React Native app. To enable custom controls in full-screen mode, you need to make a small modification.

Instead of setting controls: { hide: true } in the fullscreen prop, you can provide a custom component for the controls using the customControls prop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).